How to handle a section which itself has scrollable content in ReactPageScroller?
I'm using ReactPageScroller. I've 4 sections. The third section has some content which must be scrollable. Now, when I'm going to that section, the whole page scrolling is overriding the section scroll. How can I handle it.
<ReactPageScroller>
 <Section1 />
 <Section2 />
 <Section3 />
 <Section4 />
</ReactPageScroller>

